# Is it possible to extend each element of an array from a default object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm have an object which holds the input parameters of a function. I've also got an object holding a set of default parameters. I can easily use `$.extend` to get the final list. However, one of the parameters (`items`) is an array of objects, which I'd like to be extended similarly. I have a solution below, but I'm not sure that it is the correct way to go about it. Is there a better way to extend in this case?

```
var myParams = {
    height: 600,
    items: [
        { name: "Apple" },
        { name: "Banana", active: false },
        { name: "Orange" }
    ]
};
var defaults = {
    height: 400,
    width: 200,
    items: {
        name: "",
        active: true
    }
};
var finalParams = $.extend({}, defaults, myParams);
$.each(finalParams.items, function(i){
    finalParams.items[i] = $.extend({}, defaults.items, this);
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a deep copy? If so, see [jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) :)

Comment: Having reread your question, I think this is probably the only way you can do it - you have to loop through the items in `myParams` and extend each one against your default item.